# Cauchy criterion for series proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$  converges if and only if $\forall\ \varepsilon > 0, ∃\ N$ such that if $m > n > N$ then $|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k |<\varepsilon.$

Could you please help me with that, how can I prove it for both sides?

Comment: We know that sequences converge (in $\mathbb{R}$) if and only if they are Cauchy.  A series is defined as the limit of its sequence of partial sums.  And the Cauchy criterion above is exactly the condition that the sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : Use the Cauchy criterion known for the sequences to the partial sums of your series.

---

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$, with Cauchy criterion for the sequence $S_n$ you have :

$$S_n \text{ converges}
\\ \iff \forall \epsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n\geq m>N,|S_n-S_m|<\epsilon \\\iff \forall \epsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n\geq m>N,\left|\sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: how can I use that ,this is my struggle ?

Comment: I will add details

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m220-00/cauchy.pdf I find this for sequence but my problem I do not know how can I use it for series

Comment: Do you understand now ?

Comment: thanks , I try to do it now

Comment: why the sn= $\sum$ from 0 to n not from 0 to infinity?

Comment: It is the partial sum associated to the series :  remember a series converges if the sequence of its partial sums converges.

Comment: S_m will be for what ?I am confuse on it

Comment: $S_n$ is the sum for $i$ from $0$ to $n$ $S_m$ is the sum from $0$ to $m$